# iframe not working in PhoneGap

Tags: javascript, html, xcode, phonegap

I'm trying to display an iframe of a website in my PhoneGap app but it does not show when I emulate the app on Xcode. It shows when I it open in my browser at the IP address, but when I actually emulate it, the iframe is blank. I added

```
<allow-intent href="*" />
<allow-navigation href="*" />
<allow-navigation href="http://*/*" />
<allow-navigation href="https://*/*" />
<allow-navigation href="data:*" />
```

to my config.xml file, but it still isn't working. I'm fairly new to PhoneGap, does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

look this http://docs.phonegap.com/en/4.0.0/guide_appdev_whitelist_index.md.html

```
<access origin="*.google.*" />
```